# Clipboard addon to remove text formatting

Tags: windows, clipboard, text-editing

I was just wondering if anyone know of a Windows application that will remove formatting from any text in the clipboard?  So if I copy something from Word into another document, the content is pasted as the original text without formatting.  I want this to work no matter what application I paste into.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Puretext](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) does everything you want - and only that.

Comment: great! And the program is only 83 KB

Answer (score 3):

I achieve this by pasting in to Notepad (or your text-only editor of choice) and re-copying.

Works when copying from anywhere to anywhere.

But, I imagine this isn't *quite* what you're looking for - but it works...

Answer (score 3):

As with many small tasks, AutoHotkey is perfect for the job!

```
^#v::
   ClipboardTemp = %ClipBoardAll%
   ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%
   Send ^v
   sleep, 30
   ClipBoard = %ClipboardTemp%
Return
```

Would paste de-formatted text when you pressed control-win-v

Comment: One small caveat that may or may not apply to you: If your text contains Unicode characters, AutoHotkey will get a "downgraded" version of the characters when it reads the clipboard as text.

Comment: Add to this that this script can paste files/folders paths by copying the folder/file itself then Ctrl+Win+V, Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

That's a hotkey that works in many cases.  (e.g. I just tried it in Chrome with GMail.)

Comment: This is paste formatting in Office.